# Can't retrieve extisting document with Morphia 2.0.2

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, morphia

A document is create manually on the database, let's call this collection Employee.
I just create a class, with all the correct annotation, and then I try to query the database in order to retrieve my manually inserted Employee.
It doesn't work.

Then I create my document using Morphia directly, and I can retrieve it correctly.

I saw an `_t` property on the document, and on all its embedded class.

I've tried adding that property to my document and everything works fine.

The problem is that I have a huge database with existing documents: what am I supposed to do?
add those properties to all documents and al "embedded" ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create the document manually, you must include the `discriminator` and `discriminatorKey` in that document.  If you have your entity configured to used the discriminator (which is on by default), Morphia won't find those documents because the query will look for that discriminator as part of the query.

Comment: If you're using existing documents without those fields, it's probably simpler to just turn off the discriminator use via `@Entity`.

Comment: So I should remove the @Entity annotation? Or the alias that i'm using in the annotation?

Comment: No, you can simply add `useDiscriminator = false` to the annotation.  `@Entity` is required by Morphia.